# Building a T flip-flop with enable and reset using only a JK flip-flop that has no enable or reset, and use some necessary logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, reset, karnaugh-map, enable

I am confused about whether if I should use don't cares to fill in the J and K on the state table, or just use keep and change. If I use don't cares I will not get any Q inputs (as seen on the K-maps), thus I am not sure if I can design the flip-flop correctly or not without the Q.

[image: with don't cares][image: without the don't cares, only keep and change]

Comment: As J and K are connected together there aren't any "don't care" states to worry about. Combine J and K into a single column and you won't have any.

Comment: @Finbarr by combining J and K together, that means I should make J and K in 1 K-map, (like the one shown in the 2nd picture), and for the Q(t+1), it can only keep/change?

Comment: The second picture is not your attempt at a solution, then?

Comment: @Finbarr it is, I have made the flip-flop by combining both J and K together in the 2nd picture. I wasn't sure at first because I thought I must include the don't cares, but I guess since we should not worry about the don't cares, this solution should work, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use Don't cares for `J` and `K`. The reason for this is `J` and `K` are **not** inputs in your circuit. Furthermore, As `J` and `K` are connected together, `J` = `K`.
Don't cares are only for inputs.

Reference:

[Wikipedia: Don't care term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t-care_term)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2jtcl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above circuit is a T Flip-Flop using J-K Flip-Flop and logic gates. It has Active High Enable and Active High Reset. The Reset is asynchronous.

Comment: thanks! therefore, is the 2nd picture the correct way to build the flip-flop?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, the precedence is Enable, Reset, then Toggle. If enable = 0, Q+ will always stay the same as Q. But if Enable = 1 and reset = 1, Q+ will always be 0, otherwise we look at the T.